# Scraping the top 100 movie list off the website

Tags: r, rvest

I know there are a few ways to scrap the data from the web, but what would be the least painful way to scrap the top 100 movie list from this site: https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/guide/best-sci-fi-movies-of-all-time/

I would like to use R if possible and store the results as R file.

Many thanks!

Comment: Scraping that site is against the ToS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

url <- paste0("https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/guide/best-sci-fi-movies-of-all-time/", 1:7, "/")

all_titles <- character()
all_years <- numeric()

for (i in 1:length(url)) {
    movies <- url[i] %>%
        read_html() %>%
        html_nodes(".article_movie_title")

    titles <- movies %>%
        html_nodes("a") %>%
        html_text()

    years <- movies %>%
        html_nodes(".start-year") %>%
        html_text()

    all_titles <- c(all_titles, titles)
    all_years <- c(all_years, years)
}

result <- data.frame(Titles = all_titles, Years = all_years)

print(result)
```

Comment: thank you, is there a way to add the year the movie was made to the list like a data frame?

Comment: Yes. You can check the new solution.

Comment: thank you very much